# Bash script with smaller scripts internally

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a sequence of small bash scripts that I need to run in a particular order.

I figured I could do this by creating a script that executes each script, one after the other, because most of the scripts take input from the output files of the previous.

However, when I try to execute the script, it tries to run each of the internal scripts at once, and returns a lot of `no such file or directory` errors.

I have my script formatting like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
bash script1.sh
bash script2.sh
bash script3.sh
```

And I do not want to run script2.sh until script1.sh has finished executing. Is there a simple way to do this?

Edit: I forgot to mention that I have a few python scripts in the list as well. Not sure if that changes anything.

Comment: If *most of the scripts take input from the output files of the previous*, why don't you just start `script2.sh` at the end of `script1.sh` and so forth?

Comment: The code you show should not start script2 until script1 completes. Unless script1 does stuff in the background. You'll need to provide more details about how the scripts are written.

Comment: @glennjackman Agreed. Executing in parallel is unexpected behavior, but that might not be the problem here and it's a "debug my code" question. I expect "script[1-3].sh" are not in the cwd, so `no such file or directory` is more likely bash saying it doesn't know what to make of `script1.sh`. Should be `bash /path/to/your/script1.sh` or simpler still without the prefix, `/path/to/your/script1.sh`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct solution for you depends on what you want:

- Combining the scripts with `&&` will only execute the second if the first **exits successfully**
- Combining the scripts with `||` will only execute the second if the first **doesn't exit successfully**

If you want the second command to be executed after the first **no matter** whether it exits successfully or not, you can use **either `;` or `& wait`**:

```
bash script1.sh ;
bash script2.sh & wait
bash script3.sh
```

Comment: Semi colon worked for me and seems to be the simplest solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could try sourcing the scripts

```
#!/bin/bash
. script1.sh
. script2.sh
. script3.sh
```

If there are variables that must be removed after each script, enclose it in parentheses, i.e.

```
#!/bin/bash
(
    . script1.sh
)
(
    . script2.sh
)
(
    . script3.sh
)
```

Another possiblility is to call the scripts directly:

```
#!/bin/bash
./script1.sh
./script2.sh
./script3.sh
```

If you want all background processes spawned by the scripts to finish, add
`wait` to wait for them

eg.

```
./script1.sh
wait
./script2.sh
```

---

Your current solution is running concurrently as `bash` opens a new shell and executes that

Comment: I don't understand your point about braces. They only delimit a block of code. Maybe you are thinking of parentheses, which delimit a block of code *and* open a subshell?

Comment: @wjandrea I just checked. You're right. I must be thinking of C syntax

Answer (score 1):

Do it as this way.

```
bash script1.sh && bash script2.sh && bash script3.sh
```

Or this way:

```
bash script1.sh &&
bash script2.sh &&
bash script3.sh
```

This will ensure if previous script exited successfully, then next script will execute.

Or use `;` instead whether you need to execute next script apart of previous script is exited success or failed.

```
bash script1.sh ; bash script2.sh ; bash script3.sh
```

Comment: So what about when a script **doesn't** exit successfully, but one nevertheless want the next one(s) to be executed?

Comment: One long line might be ugly and unclear with long paths etc. – where can one add line breaks?

Comment: @dessert see update, also when user wants to execute next script once first is exited successfully or not instead of using `&&`, s/he could use `||`

Comment: `||` will **only** execute the following command(s) if the previous doesn't exit successfully, but isn't there a way to combine both?

Comment: @dessert correction `;` not `||` will cause execute next command if first exited success or failed

Comment: And same for python scripts: `script1.py; script2.py; script3.py`  or `script1.py && script2.py && script3.py` - if the scripts are marked as executable.

Comment: this is not only for scripts, it's can be any command/script

Answer (score 0):

Add `set -e` to the beginning of all the scripts. When this option is on, any command failing will cause the whole script to fail, like what would happen if commands were separated with '&&'. [the spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set)

"most of the scripts take input from the output files of the previous" sounds like what `make` is for. Consider using it.